# ArrayList<String> IndexOutOfBound

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in programming and I'm working on a note taking programm. You can add, edit, delete notes. The program was working but I wanted to make it that it makes a file where the notes are saved like this: `Header§Note;` so i have to use `String.split()` 2 times.
The notes are successfully loaded and split works too, but when i want to set the variables it doesn't work.

I hope you can help me.

```
private void splitFile(String input) {

    ArrayList<String> listOfNotes = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(input.split(";")));
    String[] notes;

    for(int i=0; i<listOfNotes.size(); i++) {
        notes = listOfNotes.get(i).split("§");
        System.out.println(notes[0] + " " + notes[1]);
        organizers.get(i).setHeader(notes[0]);
        organizers.get(i).setNote(notes[1]);
    }       
}
```

I get a `IndexOutOfBoundException` when `organizers.get(i).setHeader(notes[0]);` is called.This is the `setHeader` Method.

```
public void setHeader(String s) {
    header = s;
}
```

Edit: This is the Organizer class:

```
public class Organizer {    

private String header = new String("");
private String note = new String("");

public Organizer() {
    this("", "");
}
public Organizer(String h, String n) {
    header = h;
    note = n;
}

public String getHeader() {
    return header;
}

public String getNote() {
    return note;
}

public void setHeader(String s) {
    header = s;
}

public void setNote(String s) {
    note = s;
}

public String toString() {
    return String.format("\n\n%s\n\n%s", header, note);
}
```

}

This is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at com.ThalerPhilipp.Menu.splitFile(Menu.java:135)
at com.ThalerPhilipp.Menu.readNotesFromFile(Menu.java:116)
at com.ThalerPhilipp.Menu.showMenu(Menu.java:17)
```

### at com.ThalerPhilipp.Main.main(Main.java:9)

EDIT: I got it working. 
I got it working. I replaced the

```
organizers.get(i).setHeader(notes[0]);
organizers.get(i).setNote(notes[1]);
```

with

```
organizers.add(new Organizer(notes[0], notes[1]));
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Quite possibly `organizers.size() != listOfNotes.size()`

Comment: Please show the declaration of organizers, and whatever you are adding to it. My guess is that the size of organizers is not as large as the size of listOfNots

Comment: what is the value of `i` when you get the exception?

Comment: The exception occurs on the first loop. i==0

Answer (score 1):

You try to access non existing index in `organizers`.

Put in mind that you iterate over all elements in `listOfNotes` and try to update an element in `organizers` for each one.

So `organizers` length must be at least as `listOfNotes.size()`.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @baraky i agree..for that question your ans is valid

Comment: Bit of both. Combination of the answer and the need for clarification.

Comment: @baraky Make it an answer, not a question. A little explanation will be very helpful. Answers shouldn't include `?` unless it's part of your explanation.

Comment: Can't this line throw exception ? `System.out.println(notes[0] + " " + notes[1]);`

Comment: @baraky if you do that, then **it's a comment, not an answer**. An answer **gives a straight solution**.

Comment: Updated my answer. The cause is now given straight and no need for any more thinking.

Comment: @Noob UnChained as po stated, the exception is thrown after this line, so no.

Answer (score 1):

This is because

`organizers.size() != listOfNotes.size()`

i.e either `organizers` has not been initialized or it's size doesn't match with `listOfNotes` size

Comment: Can't this line throw exception ? `System.out.println(notes[0] + " " + notes[1]);`

Comment: @NoobUnChained op mentioned that the error is at `organizers.get(i).setHeader(notes[0]);`

Comment: I added this line to look if the String values were properly read.

Comment: @user2304533 after looking at your edit,i guess either you have not initialized organizers i.e `List<Organizer> organizers=new ArrrayList();` **or** the string you are splitting doesn't have a `;`

Comment: private ArrayList<Organizer> organizers = new ArrayList<Organizer>(); I have it like this. If the string wouldn't have a ; it should continue working

Comment: @user2304533 If the string wouldn't have a `;`,then notes would have nothing in it..